# Angular, how to create a spy object on service variable

Tags: angular, testing, rxjs, karma-jasmine, spy

I want to test my component which use a service. I dont want to use npm libraries or create mock files. I want to use spy object.

Let assume the service looks like this:

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: root
} 
export class MyService {
  isReady: Subject<boolean>;
  // etc more code
}
```

Inside my spec.ts file:

```js
// Includes

describe('myComponent', () => {
// Some boilerplate code
let mockMyService;

beforeEach(() => {

    mockMyService = jasmine.createSpyObj('MyService', ['isReady']);
});

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
   // Some declarations. 
],
providers: [
   { provide: MyService, useValue: mockMyService} 
}]);

beforeEach(() => {
   mockMyService.isReady.and.returnValue(of({}));
});
```

As you see, i want to mock a variable(Subject) of a service.
But my code above doesnt work.

How to do that?
Thanks is in advance.

Comment: `useValue: { isReady: of(true) }`? It's not a return value, it's not a *method*.

Comment: `of` returns an Observable, not a `Subject`. What exactly do you want is to do? Why not `mockMyService.isReady = new Subject();`?

Comment: @Liam, jonrsharpe thank you! You right! I didnt know that the lines you write are possible....

Comment: @BaruchLevin :Refer https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49 . this will surely help you to understand diff scenarios and adopt best practices

Comment: @Shashank Vivek thank you! good article!

Comment: @BaruchLevin: Thanks . Do check out other 2-3 unit testing articles as well. IT'll cover most of the testing scenarios . Do clap as well :)